# TDD with RSpec and Rails: testing controller actions with no view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

As I continue to learn my way around TDD with RSpec 2 and Rails 3.1, I can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

I have a Users controller with a new and create action. In my UsersController spec, I have

**users_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe "POST 'create'" do
  before(:each) do
    @attr = Factory.attributes_for(:user)
  end

  it "should assign an @user variable" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    assigns[:user].should_not be_nil
    assigns[:user].should be_kind_of(User)
  end
end
```

and in my UsersController,

**users_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
end
```

This spec is failing with

```
1) UsersController POST 'create' should assign an @user variable
   Failure/Error: post :create, :user => @attr
   ActionView::MissingTemplate:
```

I can continue to implement application code to get this test to pass, but I feel like this test should be passing as it is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `create` method needs to do something. Either render a template or redirect. Since you're not telling it to redirect it's assuming that you want it to render a template but when it can't find a `create.html.erb` file it throws an error.

You're best bet is to do either this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

or this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Comment: I see, I thought the test would (and should) pass because it does assign an @user variable. In other words, the application code is doing what I'm testing for. It seems that I need to implement more application code than is needed for the test to pass, since I'm not yet testing what template gets rendered or where the user is redirected.

Comment: Right. In testing there are errors and failures. Your test isn't experiencing a failure (that would be if @user was `nil` or wasn't a `User`), it's erroring out. Either a failure or an error is considered an unsuccessful test.

Comment: Thanks for the help aNoble. I guess I'll keep my pattern for controller tests to first test for the right render/redirect, then go on to what else should happen.

Answer (score 3):

To test rendering nothing you'll want:

```
expect(response).to render_template(nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

I've come across this recently myself. It seems one possibility would be to rescue the error in your test.

```
it "should assign an @user variable" do
  begin
    post :create, :user => @attr
  rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
    # This is okay because(/as long as) we test the render/redirect
    # in a separate spec where we don't rescue this exception.
  end
  assigns[:user].should_not be_nil
  assigns[:user].should be_kind_of(User)
end
```

I don't know how "correct" this solution is. On one hand, it definitely emphasizes the "testing one thing at a time" mentality, on the other, it seems kind of ugly.

**Edit**

I suppose you could make some nice wrappers in your spec helper, something like

```
def post?(action, params = {})
  post action, params
rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
end
```

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make sense that RSpec controller tests are following renders/redirects and producing errors.

Comment: Exception handling should be exceptional